# How to reference the Folder Before using Relative Path?

Tags: excel, vba, relative-path

I created a macro to transform Excel sheets into csv files.

The Excel file is in the folder "C:\Files\Excel". I want the csv files to be saved in "C:\Files\Csv".

Assuming I'm within the Excel folder, I have to go to the folder before ("C:\Files") then add the CSV.

It has to be relative path, because there are several files in different folders.

Comment: Please share the code on how are you `transforming` Excel Sheets to Csv?

Comment: Do you mean the csv folder is in the same folder where the Excel folder lies?

Comment: I have several ideas: check to see that the folder is there - if not, create it. Check the help or a tutorial for the `Dir` command or `FileSystemObject`, then use the new path when saving instead of the old. Add your findings to the question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an exact answer but it's very easy to take it from here. This code will give you the path of folder one level up. Simply add `Csv" to it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim CurPath As String, NewPath As String
    Dim pos As Long

    '~~> Get the path where the current file resides
    CurPath = Left$(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\"))

    '~~> This check is requried so that we know that there is a folder
    '~~> one level up. This doesn't take into account network paths
    '~~> like \\mycomputer\myfolder\ For this you will have to have a separate check.
    pos = InStr(1, CurPath, "\")
    pos = InStr(pos + 1, CurPath, "\")

    If pos > 0 Then
        '~~> This will give you folder one level up
        Debug.Print Left$(Left(CurPath, Len(CurPath) - 1), InStrRev(Left(CurPath, Len(CurPath) - 1), "\"))
    Else
        Debug.Print "You are already in the root foder"
    End If
End Sub
```